# Re-running scala program in eclipse ide after renaming

Tags: java, eclipse, scala

first i created a scala class inside a scala project in eclipse ide as below and ran it, it was successful.

```
object Test extends App{
  println("hi");
}
```

once i rename the object , i can not find any option to run the program. [The file name is not changed and build automatically was enabled]

```
object Test1 extends App{
  println("hi");
}
```

any advice ?

Comment: How did you run it?

Comment: right click on the file then Run As--> Scala Application

Answer (score 0):

Try to change launch configs for your application. Clean target folder before re-build. For config you can refer to:

> Select `Run > Run Configurations...` or `Run > Debug Configurations...` from the workbench menu bar.  This opens a dialog
>   that lets you create, modify, and delete launch configurations of
>   different types.